# Запись элементов строки в массив

Tags: c++, c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char* limits = " ,-!";
    char str[20];
    char save_str[10][10];
    int len[10];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Full the string\n");
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);
    char* str1 = strtok(str, limits);

    while (str1 != NULL)
    {
        len[i] = strlen(str1);
        save_str[i][10] = *str1;
        printf("%s\n", str1, strlen(str1));
        str1 = strtok(NULL, limits);
        i++;
    }

    printf("new\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", save_str[j][len[j]]);
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выберите конкретный язык программирования. C и C++ имеют разные средства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала после предложения с fgets

```
fgets(str,20,stdin);
```

напишите

```
str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Вместо этого предложения

```
save_str[i][10] = *str1;
```

запишите

```
strncpy( save_str[i], str1, 10 );
save_str[i][9] = '\0';
```

А также вместо этого предложения

```
printf("%s\n", str1, strlen(str1));
```

напишите либо

```
printf("%d: %s\n", len[i], str1 );
```

или просто

```
puts( str1 );
```

Также это предложение следует исправить

```
printf("%s\n",save_str[j][len[j]]);
```

Например,

```
printf("%s\n",save_str[j]);
```

или

```
puts( save_str[j] );
```

Comment: не помогает http://pastebin.com/v7BMEefF

Comment: @MarkKoval Что именно за проблема на этот раз?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp6UA.png не компилируется

Comment: @MarkKoval Ошибки компиляции вы уж сами исправляйте.

Comment: но в чом же здесь ошибка может быть(долго думал)

Comment: @MarkKoval Вы по крайней мере внесите все изменения, которые я указал. Вы даже этого не сделали.

Comment: @MarkKoval Измените последнее предложение с printf,

Comment: спасибо за помощь вышло когда запустил visual 2010